# window.bind function causing ie7 to not respond because of a long running script

Tags: jquery, windows, internet-explorer-7

I'm using the following script for a responsive menu. In IE7 the script makes the page freeze and it says the page "is not responding due to a long running script". I found that the bit causing the freezing is the `window.bind` portion at the bottom of the code and from my research so far suggests that it's causing an infinite loop in IE7. I've read answers about using setTimeout and such, but I'm very novice and have no idea how to implement this into the script. Any ideas how I can prevent this script from crashing/freezing IE7?

Here's a solution that involved the timeout on [this blog post](http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/Guido/post/2010/03/04/How-to-prevent-Stop-running-this-script-message-in-browsers), but I have no idea how to implement it with my script below

```
/* Sample scripts for RWD nav patterns 
(c) 2012 Maggie Wachs, Filament Group, Inc - http://filamentgroup.com/examples/rwd-nav-   patterns/GPL-LICENSE.txt
Last updated: March 2012
Dependencies: jQuery
 */



jQuery(function($){

$('.nav-primary')
  // test the menu to see if all items fit horizontally
  .bind('testfit', function(){
        var nav = $(this),
            items = nav.find('a');

        $('body').removeClass('nav-menu');                    

        // when the nav wraps under the logo, or when options are stacked, display the nav as a menu              
        if ( (nav.offset().top > nav.prev().offset().top) || ($(items[items.length-1]).offset().top > $(items[0]).offset().top) ) {

           // add a class for scoping menu styles
           $('body').addClass('nav-menu');

        };                    
     })

  // toggle the menu items' visiblity
  .find('h3')
     .bind('click focus', function(){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('expanded')
     });   

// ...and update the nav on window events
$(window).bind('load resize orientationchange', function(){
   $('.nav-primary').trigger('testfit');
});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out this article by John Resig http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Basically, he suggests rather than binding your function directly to the event have the function run every 250ms.

```
var outerPane = $details.find(".details-pane-outer"),
    didScroll = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if ( didScroll ) {
        didScroll = false;
        // Check your page position and then
        // Load in more results
    }
}, 250);
```

That will be far more efficient when the browser if firing many events and the same time. You won't have the resize event running 20 times at the start of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the info though I'm not sure I have the knowledge to implement it with what I have. Could you please give me an example with using the setInterval in my script?